# remove shadow from fusion table layer polygon and polyline google map v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon, google-fusion-tables, polyline

how do i hide shadow from,  fusion table layer where i add geometry like   polygon and polyline. i know it is not possible to remove shadow by using fusion table styles
can there be a workaround something like 
     var shadow = layer.getPanes();
        shadow.overlayShadow.style.dsiplay="none";

just hide all shadows from fusion tables layer on  google map v3.

Comment: The FusionTableLayer is rendered using tiles.  I would expect the shadow to be part of the tiles.  I have seen this come up several times, perhaps someone should create an enhancement request in the FusionTables [issue list](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/) or the Google Maps API [issue list](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/).

Comment: Maybe you could also post an example where the "shadows" you want removed are obvious, I don't see them (but I only looked quickly)